# Determine row number when button is clicked in this row

Tags: android

I have a ListView and each row contains button. I don't want to assign to each button its own listener object, cause it will create a lot of objects. But the question is how to determine row number or contextual information when button is clicked?

Comment: have you considered the option of making a listener for the click on the row instead of putting a button inside it? because in that case it's easier to understand which row was clicked and perform a different action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every View (including Button) can be "identified" via its [`setId(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)) method.

When clicked you will be passed a view to a [`View.OnClickListener.onCLick(view)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html#onClick(android.view.View)). Just extract the ID and you'll know which button this is.

When creating a button:

```
button.setId(1);
```

and when this button is clicked:

```
button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      int id = view.getId();
      // do something with the Id
    }
});
```

**Update:** answer was updated based on @Octavian Damiean's comment: for identifying Views `setId()` should be used instead of `setTag()`.

Comment: `setTag()` should not be used for identification. Tags don't have to be unique in their hierarchy. `setId()` should be used for identification.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. Well setTag `could` be used for that, but this is not it's task. I'm updating the answer. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, I forgot about tags. great answer! P.S. before it I made code going to parent view and parent view and then to child view. not the best way)

Comment: @Octavian: Javadoc says: The identifier does not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy. It seems that ID behaves the same as tag. The difference is that it's an int not an Object, and thus easier to store/retrieve/compare. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)

Comment: Hmm you're right. An integer should be more efficient anyway.

Answer (score 0):

using the

```
listview..setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int rowNumber,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

we can get the clicked row

Comment: He is not clicking on a row, but on a Button inside a row.

Comment: but I have button inside item, user clicks on it